# Inverse function to $f(t)=3t+4ln(t+1)=y$

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

I have to invert the function $f(t)=3t+4\ln(t+1)=y$, so $f^{-1}(y)=t$. But I am struggling to invert this. Is there a solution?

Comment: It can be inverted in terms of the Lambert W function, but there is no solution in elementary functions.

Comment: Looks to me like it will involve  "Lambert's W function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lambert W function $W(y)=z$ has the property that if $y=ze^z$, then $z=W(y)$.

So the standard approach is to try to get the expression into the form $Y=Te^T$, where $T$ is something from which we can easily get $t$ and $Y$ is a function of  $y$.

So in this case we start by exponentiating both sides: $e^{\frac{y}{4}}=(1+t)e^{\frac{3}{4}t}$. Multiply both sides by $\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{3}{4}}$ we get $\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{y+3}{4}}=\frac{3}{4}(1+t)e^{\frac{3}{4}(1+t)}$

Hence if we set $Y=\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{y+3}{4}}$ and $T=\frac{3}{4}(t+1)$ the equation becomes $Y=Te^T$. So we can use the property of the Lambert function to get $T=W(Y)$, so $t=-1+\frac{4}{3}W(\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{y+3}{4}})$.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to follow the steps, but don't understand how you got the answer. Everything after "Hence," is a mystery to me. Could you elaborate it please.

Comment: If you define $Y,T$ as shown you should find that $e^{\frac{y}{4}}=(1+t)e^{\frac{3}{4}t}$ becomes $Y=Te^T$.

Comment: Still not working for me. I've tried Y=Te^T and don't get the answer you display. And my Y has the exponential {(y-3t)/4} not {(y+3)/4} like yours.

Comment: @Orongo I have added a couple of lines. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile. Does this mean that W(Y) can be expressed as z?

Comment: Could you please expand the final step with W(0.75*exp((y+3)/4).I'm not sure how this can be expresses without W().